# Why do we have there exists a constant $c>0$ so that for any $x$, $P(\sup_{t\le T}X_t\ge x)\le P(A^c)+P(X_0\ge cx) $?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process with $t\in [0.T]$ for a fix $T>0$. Assume that on an event $A$ with probability $P(A)>0.9$, we have
$$
\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\le X_0
$$

Why do we have that there exists a constant $c>0$ so that for any $x$,
$$
P(\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\ge x)\le P(A^c)+P(X_0\ge cx)
$$

How to understand such thing like "on a high probability event, we have a upper bound"?

---

It is clear that on the event $A$, we have
$$
P(\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\ge x)\le P(X_0\ge x)
$$
but I am confused about why we need to add $P(A^c)$ when removing the "on the event A". For me this sentence means
$$
P(\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\le X_0|A)>0.9
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $c=1$.

$$ P(\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\ge x)$$ $$= P(A \cap (\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\ge x))$$ $$+P(A^{c}\cap (\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\ge x))$$ $$\le  P(X_0\ge cx)+P(A^c).$$

Comment: Thanks! But why $P(A \cap (\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\ge x))\le P(X_0\ge cx)$? It seems that  $P(A \cap (\sup_{t\le  T}X_t\ge x))\le P(X_0\ge x)$?

Comment: $c$ is at our choic .Just take $c=1$.  @Hermi